# Java Assignment ( Changing string value in if statement)

Tags: java, string, if-statement

This is the assigment. I believe I am only allowed to use If and else statements

> The following algorith yields the season (Spring, Summer, Fall, or
>   Winter) for a given month of the day.
>
> ```
> IF month is 1,2, or 3, season = "Winter
> Else if month is 4, 5, or 6, season = "Spring"
> Else if month is 7,8, 9, season = "Summer"
> Else if month is 10,11, or 12, season = "Fall"
> If month is divisible by 3 and day >= 21
>      If season is "Winter", season = "Spring"
>      Else if season is "Spring", season = "Summer"
>      Else if season is "Summer", season = "Fall"
>      Else season = "Winter"
> ```
>
> Write a program that prompts the user for a month and day and then
>   prints the season, as determined by this algorithm

Heres what I got so far. I can't get the last part to get the seasons to change if the month is divisible by 3 and day is above 20.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Seasons {

    public static void main (String[] args){

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int month;
        int day;
        String season = null;

        System.out.print("Please enter month and day: ");
        month = in.nextInt();
        day = in.nextInt();

        if(1 <= month && month <=3){
            season = "Winter";
            System.out.println(season);
        }

        else if (4 <= month && month <=6){
            season = "Spring";
            System.out.println(season);
        }

        else if (7 <=month && month <=9){
            season = "Summer";
            System.out.println(season);
        }

        else if (10 <= month && month <= 12){
            season = "Fall";
            System.out.println(season);
        }


        if ( ((month % 3 == 0) && (21 <= day)){
            if (season.equals("Winter")){

            }

            else if (season.equals("Spring")){
                season = ("Summer");
            }

            else if (season.equals("Summer")){
                season = "Fall";
            }

            else {
                season = "Winter";
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so what is your problom here! its not clear! just put  season = "Summer" inside  if (season.equals("Winter")){}

Comment: The conditions `If season is "Winter"` are redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your conditions something like this should work:

```
private String getSesson(int month, int day) {
    String season = "";
    switch (month) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
            season = "Winter";
            if(month % 3 == 0 && day >=21)
                season = "Spring";
            break;
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
            season = "Spring";
            if(month % 3 == 0 && day >=21)
                season = "Summer";
            break;
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 9:
            season = "Summer";
            if(month % 3 == 0 && day >=21)
                season = "Fall";
            break;
        case 10:
        case 11:
        case 12:
            season = "Fall";
            if(month % 3 == 0 && day >=21)
                season = "Winter";
            break;
        default:
            season = "Not a valid month";
            break;  
    }
    return season;
}
```

test:

```
    System.out.println(getSesson(1, 0));
    System.out.println(getSesson(2, 0));
    System.out.println(getSesson(3, 0));
    System.out.println(getSesson(3, 21));
    System.out.println(getSesson(4, 0));
    System.out.println(getSesson(5, 0));
    System.out.println(getSesson(6, 0));
    System.out.println(getSesson(6, 21));
    System.out.println(getSesson(7, 0));
    System.out.println(getSesson(8, 0));
    System.out.println(getSesson(9, 0));
    System.out.println(getSesson(9, 21));
    System.out.println(getSesson(10, 0));
    System.out.println(getSesson(11, 0));
    System.out.println(getSesson(12, 0));
    System.out.println(getSesson(12, 21));
```

above Syso prints:

```
Winter
Winter
Winter
Spring
Spring
Spring
Spring
Summer
Summer
Summer
Summer
Fall
Fall
Fall
Fall
Winter
```

---

If..else version:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int month, day; String season = null;
    System.out.print("Please enter month and day: ");
    month = in.nextInt(); day = in.nextInt();
    if(1 <= month && month <= 3){
        season = "Winter";
        if((month == 3) && (21 <= day))
            season = "Spring";
    } else if (4 <= month && month <=6){
        season = "Spring";
        if((month == 6) && (21 <= day))
            season = "Summer";
    } else if (7 <=month && month <=9){
        season = "Summer";
        if((month == 9) && (21 <= day))
            season = "Fall";
    } else if (10 <= month && month <= 12){
        season = "Fall";
        if((month == 12) && (21 <= day))
            season = "Winter";
    }
    System.out.println(season);
```

Comment: I don't think I can use switch for this assigment

Comment: @Bert: if `month` is integer then why not?

Comment: Is there anything in my code you see that I can change to fix the problem?

Comment: A quick view on your code shows: you forget to assign `season` variable a value at `if (season.equals("Winter")){` condition. Then remove `(` and `)` in `season = ("Summer");`. Try @Matt 's code. It seems correct.

Comment: @Bert: see my edit and don't make people do your homework for money.

Comment: I tried to do what you did but failed terribly. Anyways thanks. Lmk if you want the Pay Pal.

Comment: before i asked the question here I tried doing what you did on my own. Couldnt get it to work. Yours did. Thanks

Comment: Im just going to redo the assigment from what I learned from your code. Don't want to just copy it.

Answer (score 1):

For your own interest you can use

```
String season= "Winter,Spring,Summer,Fall".split(",")[(month + day/21 - 1)/3 &3];
```

---

```
for (int month = 1; month <= 12; month++)
    for (int day = 20; day <= 21; day++) {
        String season = "Winter,Spring,Summer,Fall".split(",")[(month + day / 21 - 1) / 3 & 3];
        System.out.println(day + "/" + month + " => " + season);
    }
```

prints

```
20/1 => Winter
21/1 => Winter
20/2 => Winter
21/2 => Winter
20/3 => Winter
21/3 => Spring
20/4 => Spring
21/4 => Spring
20/5 => Spring
21/5 => Spring
20/6 => Spring
21/6 => Summer
20/7 => Summer
21/7 => Summer
20/8 => Summer
21/8 => Summer
20/9 => Summer
21/9 => Fall
20/10 => Fall
21/10 => Fall
20/11 => Fall
21/11 => Fall
20/12 => Fall
21/12 => Winter
```

Comment: $10 pay pal if you can fix the problem using my original code.

Comment: @Bert: this is not how things work around here: no money, but upvotes.

Comment: I will gladly accept offers to donate to a charity of your choice.  In this cause you can replace everything after you read the month and day with that line. Anyone marking your work may expect you to be able to explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the modulus operator (%) to get the reminder after division like this:

```
if ((month % 3) == 0 && day >= 21)
{
  if (season.equals("Winter")) 
  { 
    season = "Summer";
  }
  // ... etc ...
}
```

Comment: It's in there. Im just having trouble getting seasons to change when those conditions are met.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's from your logical test in the if block, use brackets to test as a unit:

```
if ( ((month % 3) == 0) && (day >= 21) )
```

***Edit :***

All you need to do is to reassign the variable to the new season.

```
if ( ((month % 3) == 0) && (day >= 21) ) {
    season = "Winter";
}
```

The proceed to print in `season`

As long is the conditions all evaluate to `true`. Then the variable would be changed to `winter`. But if it is `false` it wouldn't change.

You can simply try :

```
if(true) {
   season = "Winter";
}

System.out.println(season);
```

You should see `Winter`.

Answer (score 0):

Your original algorithm looks wrong..
If you had determined in the first part that it was winter (month 1,2, or 3) and it was the 3rd month and the day was greater than the 20th, it would be Spring, not Summer..

Here is what it should say:

```
if (month % 3 == 0 && 21 <= day){
    if (season.equals("Winter")){
        season = "Spring"
    }

    else if (season.equals("Spring")){
        season = "Summer";
    }

    else if (season.equals("Summer")){
        season = "Fall";
    }

    else {
        season = "Winter";
    }
}
```

You were missing the value for Winter.

Alternatively you could do it like this:

```
public class Seasons {

  public static void main (String[] args){

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int month;
    int day;
    String season = null;

    System.out.print("Please enter month and day: ");
    month = in.nextInt();
    day = in.nextInt();
    String[] seasons = {"Winter", "Spring", "Summer", "Fall"};
    if (day >= 21 && month % 3 == 0) {
            season = seasons[((month + 2) / 3) % 4];
    } else {
            season = seasons[((month-1)/3)];
    }
    System.out.println("Season: " + season);
  }
}
```

Comment: $10 pay pal if you can fix the problem using my original code.

Comment: Look at my first solution, it was your original code (the part that was wrong).. Replace it with what you have and then it works.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem on your code (which, in general, works) is that you are printing the season value before changing it. That is why you can't see when the second part of the algoritm works.

Remove the `System.out`s on every if statement, and change them for an only one at the end of the method. Also fix your last if/elses, as the winter one is empty. 
Final code:

```
public static void main (String[] args){

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int month;
    int day;
    String season = null;

    System.out.print("Please enter month and day: ");
    month = in.nextInt();
    day = in.nextInt();

    if(1 <= month && month <=3){
        season = "Winter";
    }

    else if (4 <= month && month <=6){
        season = "Spring";
    }

    else if (7 <=month && month <=9){
        season = "Summer";
    }

    else if (10 <= month && month <= 12){
        season = "Fall";
    }


    if ( ((month % 3 == 0) && (21 <= day)){
        if (season.equals("Winter")){
            season="Spring";
        }

        else if (season.equals("Spring")){
            season = "Summer";
        }

        else if (season.equals("Summer")){
            season = "Fall";
        }

        else {
            season = "Winter";
        }


    }

    System.out.println(season);
}
```

This will print the final result (i.e "Spring" for March 22nd).

Comment: Omg that was so simple I feel dumb.

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class SeasonDetictor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         String month1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("please enter number of the month");
         String day1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("please enter number of the day");
         int month = Integer.parseInt(month1);
         int day = Integer.parseInt(day1);

         if ((month == 3)&&(day >= 21 && day <= 31) ) {    
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "spring"); 
         }

         else if ((month == 4)||(month == 5)) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "spring"); 
         }

         else if  ((month == 6) && (day < 21)) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "spring"); 
         }

         if ((month == 6)&&(day >= 21 && day <= 31) ) {    
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "summer"); 
         }

         else if ((month == 7)||(month == 8)) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "summer"); 
         }

         else if  ((month == 9) && (day < 21)) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "summer"); 
         }

         if ((month == 9)&&(day >= 21 && day <= 31) ) {    
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "fall"); 
         }

         else if ((month == 10)||(month == 11)) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "fall"); 
         }

         else if  ((month == 12) && (day < 21)) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "fall"); 
         }


         if ((month == 12)&&(day >= 21 && day <= 31) ) {    
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "winter"); 
         }

         else if ((month == 1)||(month == 2)) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "winter"); 
         }

         else if  ((month == 3) && (day < 21)) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "winter"); 
         }

    }
}
```

Comment: A description is useful.